# I am trying to populate a listview with a list of objects but only show name property, whilst allowing user to multiselect items in the listview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I recently started working on an android app for the first time.I am trying to add a list of Ingredient objects to a `listview` and get the `listview` to only show the name property on the Ingredient object.

The below code is showing the whole object in the view (`WeeklyMealGenerator.Models.Ingredient`). I also need to make sure the solution still allows me to pull the object from the selected objects

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    >
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width ="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop = "0.0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width       ="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height      ="wrap_content"
            android:text               ="Meal name:"
            android:layout_marginRight ="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6.6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop   ="5dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id            ="@+id/MealName"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width  ="190dp"
            android:layout_height ="37.5dp"
            android:inputType = "number"
            android:textSize = "12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Ingredients" />

</LinearLayout>



namespace WeeklyMealGenerator.Models
{
    public class Ingredient
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}




namespace WeeklyMealGenerator.Activities
{
    [Activity(Label = "AddMealAcitivity")]
    public class AddMealActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.AddMeal);

            Ingredient[] ingredients =
            {
                new Ingredient{Name = "Carrot"},
                new Ingredient{Name = "Steak"},
                new Ingredient{Name = "Potatoes"},
                new Ingredient{Name = "Roast Chicken"},
                new Ingredient{Name = "Pasta"},
                new Ingredient{Name = "Pasta Sauce"}
            };

            ListView listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.Ingredients);
            ArrayAdapter<Ingredient> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Ingredient>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemMultipleChoice, ingredients);
            listView.SetAdapter(adapter);
            listView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Multiple;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you dont use recyclerview. it has better control over listview. its adapter allows you to select multiple items and manipulate them

Answer (score 0):

after a couple of hours of research i finally found that it calls the ToString method on the model. I just had to override it to get it to work.

Comment: How your compiling goes, I hear people crying for compiling speed for Xamarin.